# The best practice for including header files to multiple inherited classes

Tags: c++, oop, include, header-files

Let's say we have a parent class with header `parent.h` and 2 child classes `child1.h` and `child2.h`, since they both inherit from parent, both header files should include `parent.h`. Including `child1.h` and `child2.h` in another file will result of a duplicate definition of the parent class. What is the best way to avoid this? Is using `#pragma once` a good practice, or are there other ways to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the exact reason why `#ifndef` is used as a check in header files.

For example, your `parent.h' may have:

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H

.... //Your header definition

#endif
```

Then, in `child1.h` and `child2.h`

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#include "parent.h"
#endif

....//Your source code
```

Comment: You do not need or want that `#ifndef` in the child headers.

Comment: so how do you do it instead?

Comment: @Omar Simply have each header file have its own include guards. Other files should not know or care what the names of those guards are.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use pragma or #ifndef

```
#ifndef _AUTOMOBILE_H
#define _AUTOMOBILE_H
//...
#endif
```

Comment: Names like `_AUTOMOBILE_H` which begin with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved for the C++ implementation - you should not be creating them in your own code. Simply use `AUTOMOBILE_H`